# Fancybox issues with different method to call

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, fancybox

I having trouble to call fancybox. Amateur issues. Code below works fine when i try to open a video using fancybox iframe but last code doesnt. How can i fix it?

```
<a href="javascript:;" data-href="MBHD0790-03" class="iframe" ">WORKS</a>

$(".iframe").fancybox({
  'width': 720,
  'height': 410,
  'type': 'iframe',
  'autoScale': false,
  'autoSize': false,
  'autoDimensions': false,
  'padding': 0,
  'beforeLoad' : function(){
    var url = $(this.element).data("href");
    this.href = baseURL+'assets/media-video/'+url+'.php';
  },
  'beforeShow': function(){
    $(window).on({
      'resize.iframe' : function(){
        $.fancybox.update();
      }
    });
  },
  'afterClose': function(){
    $(window).off('resize.iframe');
  }

});
```

When i use the code above my fancybox works fine, but when i try to call using another function doesnt work.

```
<a href="javascript:;" data-href="MBHD0790-03" onclick="vfancy(this)">DOESNT WORK</a>

function vfancy(){
  fancybox({
    'width': 720,
    'height': 410,
    'type': 'iframe',
    'autoScale': false,
    'autoSize': false,
    'autoDimensions': false,
    'padding': 0,
    'beforeLoad' : function(){
      var url = $(this.element).data("href");
      this.href = baseURL+'assets/media-video/'+url+'.php';
    },
    'beforeShow': function(){
      $(window).on({
        'resize.iframe' : function(){
          $.fancybox.update();
        }
      });
    },
    'afterClose': function(){
      $(window).off('resize.iframe');
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second code has 2 basic problems:

1). To call fancybox programmatically you need to invoke it within the jQuery scope like :

```
function vfancy() {
    jQuery.fancybox({
        // API options
    });
};
```

...but you are using this

```
function vfancy() {
    fancybox({
        // API options
    });
};
```

... which will never work.

2). Bear in mind that you can only use `$(this.element)` within any fancybox *callback* **if** you have bound an element to fancybox (normally the `<a>` element) but in this case you are invoking fancybox programmatically within an anonymous function so `$(this.element)` is out of context.

What you have to do is :

a). get rid of the `beforeLoad` callback altogether (which will do nothing)

b). pass the value of the `data-href` attribute as the argument of the `vfancy` anonymous function when you invoke it like

```
<a data-href="MBHD0790-03" onclick="vfancy(this.getAttribute('data-href'))" href="javascript:;" >IT WORKS NOW</a>
```

c). add the `href` API option to your fancybox function and set its value from the argument passed to the anonymous function like

```
function vfancy(url) {
    jQuery.fancybox({
        href: baseURL + 'assets/media-video/' + url + '.php',
        // other API options
    });
};
```

**Notice** the anonymous function needs to accept the argument (`vfancy(url)`). Also notice the comma after the `href` API option if you add more options below.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/83pn2qno/)**

---

**EDIT**

You can also pass `this` as argument within the `onclick` attribute like :

```
<a href="javascript:;" data-href="1_b.jpg" onclick="vfancy(this)">IT DOES WORK NOW</a>
```

... and get the value of the `data-href` attribute within the `vfancy` function like

```
function vfancy(url) {
    var url = url.getAttribute('data-href');
    jQuery.fancybox({
        href: baseURL + 'assets/media-video/' + url + '.php',
        // API options
        padding: 0 //,
    });
};
```

See updated **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/83pn2qno/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke plugin properly on the object:

```
function vfancy(obj) {
    $(obj).fancybox({
        width: 720,
        height: 410,
        type: 'iframe',
        autoScale: false,
        autoSize: false,
        autoDimensions: false,
        padding: 0,
        beforeLoad: function () {
            var url = $(this.element).data("href");
            this.href = baseURL + 'assets/media-video/' + url + '.php';
        },
        beforeShow: function () {
            $(window).on({
                'resize.iframe': function () {
                    $.fancybox.update();
                }
            });
        },
        afterClose: function () {
            $(window).off('resize.iframe');
        }
    });
};
```